# How important are the navigation rules?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation, rules

I've been working on JSF 2.1/Primefaces 3.4.1 and I've been having some troubles with my beans, like they were never instantiated but they run some of their functions and then they just stop working, does anyone knows what would be the reason of this? I've been checking for a while and I've come to the conclusion that maybe it is because I dont use any navigation rules, am I right?

Comment: You need to show an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) here

Comment: A good source to learn JSF is in [our wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), it contains a pretty basic example. After that, move to [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/) or [BalusC blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html). Also, as mentioned by kolossus, it would be great if you show us what you have and point to the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsf 2 You dont need navigation rules in xml. Instead you have the option to also specify navigation outcome directly in the EL code.

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" type="submit" action="#{myBean.view}" />
```

The returned value of myBean.view is the name of the view the user will navigate to when clicking the button

In jsf 1.x you would have to specify navigation rules in xml

```
faces-config.xml
```

If you are interested in how navigation is done the "old" way, you can look at some examples here: http://www.jsftutorials.net/jsf-navigation-by-examples.html

and read more about the differences here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or something I can study?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ here is one that uses Maven. Which Might be an extra obstacle. If you run into new problems during the tutorial, try ask questions limited to the problem at hand.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i agree that its cheap. but the question includes a part that is answeraable. about navigation rules and if they mandatory in jsf 2.

Comment: @AkselWillgert at least give a further explanation or offer more info in your answer.

Comment: @AkselWillgert, what would the myBean.view method may contain? im new with this and im a bit lost, also i've been busy the last days and i've not been able to work on this. Thx for your support guys.